# Adding columns to a sybase table with unique auto_identity index option

Tags: sap-ase, alter-table

I've inherited a Sybase database that has the 'unique auto_identity index' option enabled on it. As part of an upgrade process I need to add a few extra columns to the tables in this database i.e.

```
alter table mytable add <newcol> float default -1 not null
```

When I try to do this I get the follow error:

```
Column names in each table must be unique, column name SYB_IDENTITY_COL in table #syb__altab....... is specifed more than once
```

Is it possible to add columns to a table with this property enabled?

**Update 1:**

I created the following test that replicates the problem:

```
use master
sp_dboption 'esmdb', 'unique auto_identity indexoption',true

use esmdb

create table test_unique_ids (test_col char)

alter table test_unique_ids add new_col float default -1 not null
```

The alter table command here produces the error. (Have tried this on ASE 15/Solaris and 15.5/Windows)

**Update 2:**

This is a bug in the Sybase **dbisql** interface, which the client tools Sybase Central and Interactive SQL use to access the database and it only appears to affect tables with the 'unique auto_identity index' option enabled.

To work around the problem use a different SQL client (via JDBC for example) to connect to the database or use **isql** on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be no problem to ALTER TABLE with such columns; the err msg indicates the problem regards something else.  I need to see the CREATE TABLE DDL.

Even if we can't ALTER TABLE, which we will try first, there are several work-arounds.

**Responses**

Hah!  Internal Sybase error.  Open a TechSupport case.

Workaround:

1. Make sure you get jthe the exact DDL.  sp_help .  Note the IDENTITY columns and indices.
2. Create a staging table, exactly the same.  Use the DDL from (1). Exclude the Indices.
3. INSERT new_table SELECT old_table.  If the table is large, break it into batches of 1000 rows per batch.
4. Now create the Indices.

---

If the table is very large, AND time is an issue, then use bcp.  You need to research that first, I am happy to answer questions afterwards.

Comment: I've updated the original with some sample code that produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your sample code I first get the error:

> The 'select into' database option is not enabled for database 'mydb'. ALTER TABLE with data copy cannot be done. Set the 'select into' database option and re-run

This is no doubt because the data within your table needs copying out because the new column is not null. This will use tempdb I think, and the error message you've posted refers to a temp table. Is it possible that this dboption has been accidentally enabled for the tempdb?

It's a bit of a shot in the dark, as I only have 12.5 to test on here, and it works for me. Or it could be a bug.